# How to use Pytube to download a playlist of music files?

Tags: pytube

I have a music playlist on Youtube and I would like to download it using pytube. How do I do that? I don't want the video, only the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to download a playlist of mp4 files, without the video:

```
import pytube
playlist = pytube.Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RoKdYcvH1o&list=PLO9g5TaTqghx5yu_wAmnwUhZG_CXvW4bb')
for video in playlist.videos:
   video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download()
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://pytube.io/en/latest/) if you have more specific wishes:

- [Playlist options](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/playlist.html)
- [Filtering options](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/streams.html#filtering-streams)